# XSLT - Difference between 2 XML variables

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a case where there are 2 XML variables of the same structure. I want to get the difference between the two.

Let's say V1(represents new records) has elements a1, a2, a3, a4
and V2(represents already existing records) has elements a5, a7, a3

Here, Variable a3 which is there in V1 is existing in V2, so I want to get rid of that one and I want a new variable which holds only {a1, a2, a4}

Here are my 2 XML variables

First :

```
<ReadUsersResponse>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>aaa</EmailAddress>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <ObjectId>101</ObjectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>bbb</EmailAddress>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <ObjectId>103</ObjectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
    </User>
</ReadUsersResponse>
```

Second :

```
<ReadUsersResponse>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>ddd</EmailAddress>
        <Name>d</Name>
        <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>bbb</EmailAddress>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <ObjectId>103</ObjectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <ObjectId>107</ObjectId>
    </User>
</ReadUsersResponse>
```

Compare ObjectId's in each 
And here is what I want : (Trim ObjectId 103 as it is already available in Variable2)

```
<ReadUsersResponse>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>aaa</EmailAddress>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <ObjectId>101</ObjectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
    </User>
</ReadUsersResponse>
```

I've tried but I can't do it.

The approach I followed is to first merge these 2 XML variables into 1 variable, in 2 seperate tags
Ex

    
       ..first Var...
    
    
       ..second Var...

I'm having issues with this and can't figure it out. Is this the right approach? Or is there any alternative way? Does anyone know of a solution.

Thanks in Advance

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="kuser" match="User" 
             use="concat(ObjectId,'#', EmailAddress, '#', Name)" />
    <xsl:variable name="u2" select="document('doc_2.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="User">
        <xsl:variable name="user_found">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$u2/ReadUsersResponse" mode="checkuser" >
                <xsl:with-param name="user" select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$user_found != 'true'">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ReadUsersResponse" mode="checkuser">
        <xsl:param name="user"/>
        <xsl:if test="key('kuser', concat($user/ObjectId,'#', $user/EmailAddress, '#', $user/Name))" >
            <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() " />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate following output:

```
<ReadUsersResponse>
        <User>
                <EmailAddress>aaa</EmailAddress>
                <Name>a</Name>
                <ObjectId>101</ObjectId>
        </User>

        <User>
                <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
                <Name>c</Name>
                <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
        </User>
</ReadUsersResponse>
```

They key value `use="concat(ObjectId,'#', EmailAddress, '#', Name)"`could be adapted depending on which part of User should he checked.

For some explanation have: eg [Lookup table in a separate document](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xsltip.html)
*An essential point is that a separate index is prepared for each source document that is loaded (using the document() function).*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="first">
    <ReadUsersResponse>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>aaa</EmailAddress>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <ObjectId>101</ObjectId>
      </User>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>bbb</EmailAddress>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <ObjectId>103</ObjectId>
      </User>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
      </User>
    </ReadUsersResponse>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="second">
    <ReadUsersResponse>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>ddd</EmailAddress>
        <Name>d</Name>
        <ObjectId>104</ObjectId>
      </User>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>bbb</EmailAddress>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <ObjectId>103</ObjectId>
      </User>
      <User>
        <EmailAddress>ccc</EmailAddress>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <ObjectId>107</ObjectId>
      </User>
    </ReadUsersResponse>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="User" match="User" use="ObjectId"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$first//User">
      <xsl:variable name="ObjectId" select="ObjectId"/>
      <xsl:variable name="User">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:message>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$User"/>
      </xsl:message>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when
          test="$ObjectId = $second//User/ObjectId[preceding-sibling::EmailAddress = $User/User/EmailAddress]"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```